# Access UserControl Property From ascx file

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a function that Localize the text of my control.

```
// code behind
lblName.Text = Localization.GetLocalValue( "Updated" , this.Path );
```

and I know that i can call a function inside ascx file.

```
// ascx file
Text='<%#Global.Convert( (DateTime)(Eval("CreatedDate")) %>'
```

How can i Get **Path** Property in ascx file To call **GetLocalValue** ?

Comment: What exactly are you referring to by 'Path'? The filename? The file path? The server variables may be of use to you

Comment: @cusimar9 : it's a custom property for my control.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to create public property Path in code behind:

```
public string LocalizedPath
{
  get
    {
      return Localization.GetLocalValue( "Updated" , this.Path);
    }
}
```

And than you can use it in .aspx:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert('<%= LocalizedPath %>');
</script>
```

Comment: = i have that public property. i use it in code behind. what about <%#Localization.GetLocalValue( "Updated" , this.Path ) %>? can i write <% %> inside another <% %>?

Comment: @Raika: You no need to write <%= %> inside of another <%= %>, seems you can just <%#Localization.GetLocalValue( "Updated" , Path ) %>. Also check my answer if it will not work.

Comment: when i wrote <%#Localization.GetLocalValue( "Updated" , Path ) %> i get this error **Databinding expressions are only supported on objects that have a DataBinding event. System.Web.UI.WebControls.BoundField does not have a DataBinding event.** i use it for Gridview columns header text.

Comment: and for your answer.in javascript its work prefect but i test it in header text and it return the same error. is it because i use it for Gridview columns header text?